# Ignore spring mvc @requestbody entity null value

Tags: spring-mvc, jackson

My entity:

```
public class DeviceTypeDTO {
   @Size(max = 20)
   private String name="asd";

   public String getName() {
       return name;
   }

   public void setName(String name) {
       this.name = name;
   }
}
```

My controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/deviceTypes",
        method = RequestMethod.POST,
        produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@Timed
public APIResult createDeviceType(@Valid @RequestBody DeviceTypeDTO dto) {
    ...
}
```

If I get a post like

```
{
 "name":null
}
```

I want the `dto.name` to use a default value. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

You can use  `@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)`, and add some logic in getter function, such as return default value if value is null

Answer (score 0):

Now, my approach is to use AOP to deal with the unified, traversing the entity for the NULL attribute to deal with the default value